# Filter using JComboBox and JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, jcombobox

I have a table, and I want to search/filter in it by using a `JTextField`. I have the code to do that, and it is working.

Now, what I want to do is, by a `JComboBox`, select for what *Column* I want to search and show me the entire rows with what I searched.

[image: Example]

This is the code I got so far:

```
private  void Filtro(String query){
     DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) TabelaPessoal.getModel();
     TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> pesquisa = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(modelo);
     TabelaPessoal.setRowSorter(pesquisa); 

     pesquisa.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));             
 }

private void txt_pesquisaKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
    String query = txt_pesquisa.getText().toLowerCase();
    Filtro(query);
}
```

How I can do that?

Comment: (1-) Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/690025/java/Filter-ComboBox-TextField. Yesterday you got a link to the Swing tutorial that provides a working example on how to filter a table based on data in a given column. The column is hard coded but you should easily be able to modify that code to get the column from the combo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code

```
public class ColumnName {
    public String columnName;
    public int columnIndex;

    public ColumnName( String columnName, int columnIndex ) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;


    public String toString() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public int getColumnIndex() {
        return columnIndex;
    }
}

public JComboBox createComboBox( TableModel model ) {
    int count = model.getColumnCount();
    Object[] items = new Object[count];
    for( int i = 0 ;i < count;i++ ) {
        String columName = model.getColumnName(i);
        items[i] = new ColumnName( columName,i);
    }
    return new JComboBox(items);
}

JComboBox columnCombo = createComboBox( TabelaPessoal.getModel() );

private  void Filtro(String query){
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) TabelaPessoal.getModel();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> pesquisa = new 
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(modelo);
    TabelaPessoal.setRowSorter(pesquisa); 

    ColumnName columnName = ( ColumnName  ) columnCombo.getSelectedItem();
    pesquisa.setRowFilter( RowFilter.regexFilter(query, columnName.getColumnIndex() ) );             
}
```